# Want to align image in front of text but at center

Tags: html

I want to align image in front of text and in the middle .

```html
<div id="info">
      <ul>
        <h3>
          <li>NAME: Mohit Kumar Singh</li>
          <li>CONTACT:1234567890</li>
          <li>ADDERESS:police line</li>
        </h3>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="over" style="width:100%; height:100%" align="center">
     <img src="mks.jpg" height="150" width=120" >
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean 'in front'? Do you want to render the image above/below/left/right, or on top of the text?

Comment: I think he means 'next to' - ie. to the right of

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the image and the text to be displayed on the same link, then this should work:

I added a container div around both divs and then displayed them inline-block (inline to be on the same line, block so that the image can have a width).

However, for this to work, your style for `id="over"` was removed.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#container div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="info">
    <h3>
      <ul>
        <li>NAME: Mohit Kumar Singh</li>
        <li>CONTACT:1234567890</li>
        <li>ADDERESS:police line</li>
      </ul>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="over">
    <img src="mks.jpg" height="150" width="120">
  </div>
</div>
```